# When drawing a simple line, how to prevent anti-aliasing and keep multiple lines in one layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to draw multiple simple straight solid lines without anti-aliasing and without creating multiple layers for every time I change direction or make a new line.  I need to use the line tool...the pencil is too erratic for the length of the line.

Answer (score 2):

With the Line Tool active make sure the "Pixels" mode is selected and un-check "Anti-alias" in the top bar. Be aware that this is drawing pixels on a raster image layer and your lines aren't editable as vector shape layers would be.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  You must have a newer version.  I failed to indicate I am using PS 7.  I never saw my PhotoShop UI look like yours, but with those tools it would be easy.  I'm not sure but I don't think I can put lines in a vector layer in PS 7.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 7? I have no idea. That is a very old version!

Answer (score 1):

I found a more direct method.

1. Create a new layer or select a raster layer of choice.
2. Open the PENCIL tool (my mistake was I had the BRUSH tool open).
3. Enter the SIZE of the line desired, and MODE to normal.
4. Create your line.  The <kbd>shift</kbd> key will hold line horizontal, vertical or 45°.

This method is for Photoshop 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Edit > Preferences > General...** or press **Ctrl + K** then try changing the interpolation to **Nearest Neighbor (preserve hard edges)**

[image]